# Draw text on image using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qimage, drawtext

I want to draw text on an image. I use this code, but I do not see any text on the image.

```
void ImageSaver::save(const QString &path) const {       
   QImage image(img_);
   QPainter p(&image);
   p.setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
   p.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont::Bold));
   p.drawText(image.rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Text");
   image.save(path);
}
```

Comment: You would need to display or save the image again after adding the text, or restructure your code to draw the text then save the image.  Right now you save it before anything is changed.

Comment: I edit code, but it was useless.

Comment: Pay careful attention to which image you are passing to the painter and which you are saving.  They do not match.

Answer (score 9):

`QPainter` must finish the I/O operations before the image is valid. You can either do it *after* `QPainter` object destruction or use the `begin`/`end` methods.

```
bool ImageSaver::save(const QString &path) const {    
  QImage image(img_);
  QPainter p;
  if (!p.begin(&image)) return false;

  p.setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
  p.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont::Bold));
  p.drawText(image.rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Text");
  p.end();

  return image.save(path);
}
```

P.S.: I've added the `bool` return for better error tracking.

Comment: Note: To optimize the rendering (e.g. while in paintEvent of a QWidget), prefer **QStaticText** over using p.drawText. For one-time usage, however, this solution is equivalent.